# How do I publish to docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

What do I need to do to make my images available to the public via the Docker Hub?

Some errors for search

```
The push refers to a repository docker.io/yourname/yourimage
```

or

```
Repository does not exist: docker.io/yourname/yourimage
```

Answer (score 7):

Register a [docker hub account](https://hub.docker.com/).

Run:

```
docker login
```

This will add a file that looks like so to ~/.docker/config.json:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "somekey",
            "email": "your@emailaddress.com"
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to do a

```
docker push yourname/yourimage
```